# Failed to transform react-native-0.70.6-release.aar

Tags: react-native

Packaging and publishing version report error

Execution failed for task ':expo-modules-core:generateReleaseRFile'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':expo-modules-core:releaseCompileClasspath'.
> Failed to transform react-native-0.70.6-release.aar (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.70.6) to match attributes {artifactType=android-symbol-with-package-name, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=release, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-api}.
> > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: /Volumes/DATA/project/meisucrm/node_modules/react-native/android/com/facebook/react/react-native/0.70.6/react-native-0.70.6-release.aar.
> > Failed to transform '/Volumes/DATA/project/meisucrm/node_modules/react-native/android/com/facebook/react/react-native/0.70.6/react-native-0.70.6-release.aar' using Jetifier. Reason: ZipException, message: invalid entry size (expected 911696 but got 911758 bytes). (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
> Suggestions:
> - Check out existing issues at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:460323&s=modified_time:desc, it's possible that this issue has already been filed there.
> - If this issue has not been filed, please report it at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=460323 (run with --stacktrace and provide a stack trace if possible).

Can be packed and passed normally